# Cant make GridBagLayout position with weight work

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Im attempting to make  a 3x2 grid. In the grid i want a picture and a corresponding radio button. So picture would be in (0,0) and picture in (1,0).
I couldn't get the weightx and weighty system to work and all the components stay on one line. I have removed the weights for now. Code look like this:

```
    //the two numbers are corresponding with coordinates. For field00, x=0 and y=0
    GridBagConstraints field00 = new GridBagConstraints();
    field00.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    field00.gridx = 0;
    field00.gridy = 0;
    this.add(nokiaPic, field00);
    GridBagConstraints field10 = new GridBagConstraints();
    field10.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    field10.gridx = 1;
    field10.gridy = 0;
    this.add(nokiaButton, field10);

    GridBagConstraints field01 = new GridBagConstraints();
    field01.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    field01.gridx = 0;
    this.add(princessPic, field01);
    GridBagConstraints field11 = new GridBagConstraints();
    field11.gridx = 1;
    field11.gridy = 1;
    this.add(princessButton, field11);

    To give you an idea:
    +--------+--------+
    |        |        |
    |   pic  | Button |
    |        |        |
    +--------+--------+
    |        |        |
    |   pic  | Button |
    |        |        |
    +--------+--------+
    |        |        |
    |   pic  | Button |
    |        |        |
    +--------+--------+
```

I am aware that i am not using the normal convention for GridBagConstraints but i don't see why this method shouldn't work just as well. I hope you can help me add the weight to make this look like the pictures are in left column with corresponding radio buttons in right row.

Comment: I "think: you want `gridwidth` and `gridheight` which describes the amount of cells the component can expand across

Comment: I only want each object to take up a single space. The object should be placed under each other in two columns.

Comment: Think you might need to draw a picture

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could have simply used `GridLayout` but if you still want to use `GridBagLayout` then use single `GridBagConstraints`:

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(nokiaPic, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    this.add(nokiaButton, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    this.add(princessPic, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    this.add(princessButton, gbc);
```